# "Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type" when accessing item with bottle

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I have the following code:

```
from bottle import response, error, get
import json


@get('/db_Data')
def db_Data(db):

    db.execute("SELECT id, name, category, location, date, amount FROM    inventory")
    names = db.fetchall() # Use db.fetchone() to get results one by one
    return json.dumps(names)

@get('/db_Item')
def db_Item(db):
    db.execute("SELECT id, name, category, location, date, amount FROM inventory WHERE id=?", (id, ))
    names = db.fetchall()
    return json.dumps(names)

@error(404)
def error_404_handler(e):

    return json.dumps({'Error': {'Message': e.status_line, 'Status': e.status_code}})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from bottle import install, run
    from wtplugin import WtDbPlugin, WtCorsPlugin

    install(WtDbPlugin())
    install(WtCorsPlugin())
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True, autojson=False)
```

When i want to only get  one item (2nd route) i get :

```
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

The first route works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any `id` value in that second handler. You need to capture it in the route and pass it to the function:

```
@get('/db_Item/<id>')
def db_Item(db, id):
    ...
```